# Bootstrap scroll effect for tab content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap content tab with scroll effect on mobile view.

In desktop view it is normal tab structure but when it is viewed on smaller screens, clicking on tabs it should scroll to the respective content panel.

In my demo you can see that scroll works on second time click but not on first click. Any idea what I am missing?

Need to get the scroll effect on first click itself.

```
$('.tabs-right>li a').on('click', function (e) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
        }, 'slow');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

**[Updated DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b3nhjvot/208/)**

Comment: validate your html. what is `col-md-124`? and there's one unclosed <div>. If you use bootstrap, why there's no `container` and `row`?

Answer (score 1):

You are handling click events on the same `a` elements here that bootstrap uses to trigger changing tabs in the first place, and that seems to interfere here.

Use the [events the tabs plugin provides](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events) instead to trigger you scrolling animation:

```
$('.tabs-right>li a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
        }, 'slow');
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b3nhjvot/220/

Answer (score 1):

your code has no problem but use latest version of jQuery (3.1.1) then it perfectly works :) Have fun

```
JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arifkarim/b3nhjvot/209/
```